# Where to install certificate in certmgr?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, x509certificate, mmc

I have been trying to run am ASP.Net application on localhost which uses claim based identity and it is failing with the following error.

Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue 'ee1e51a864c7f4a8d3085d0dad127a2b1a814858'.

I have the following piece of code in web.config

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PSBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="ee1e51a864c7f4a8d3085d0dad127a2b1a814858" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <defaultCertificate findValue="ee1e51a864c7f4a8d3085d0dad127a2b1a814858" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>

      <PeopleSoftFixDateBehavior />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Where do I need to check for this certificate? and how to create a new one if it does not exist?

Thank you

Comment: See [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-87b3d5a3-b68c-4023-87c4-7cc78a44d7ed?ocmsassetid=ha010034138&correlationid=7006c694-57cc-4729-be1d-2f2e2976d24f&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: I could not find anything about certificates there

Comment: You have to create a certificate with `makecert.exe` command and then install that

Comment: that command work for `developer command prompt for visual studio`. and if you have visual studio you had it before